# After countdown has finished, how to add another countdown for 11 hours then expire

Tags: javascript

I have a countdown problem in JavaScript, I want after the countdown has finished adding another countdown for 11 hours then expires. please help me how to resolve this.

```
<script>
    <?php
    foreach ($absensi as $n) :
    ?>
    
    <?php if($n['email'] == userdata('email') && $webinar['judul']== $n['judul']){ ?>
    var countDownDate = new Date("<?= $n['tanggal_kegiatan']; ?>").getTime();
    <?php }else{ ?>

    <?php } ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    
    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

        // Get todays date and time
        var now = new Date().getTime();

        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
        var distance = countDownDate - now;

        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
        
        // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<a><font color='white'>" + days + " <span> Hari </span>:<font color='white'> " + hours + "    <span>Jam</span></font>: <font color='white'> " + minutes + " <span>Menit </span></font>: <font color='white'>" + seconds + "<span> Detik</span></font> </font> </a>";
        <?php
        foreach ($absensi as $n) :
        ?>
        
        // If the count down is finished, write some text 
        if (distance < 0) {
            clearInterval(x);
            <?php if($n['email'] == userdata('email') && $webinar['judul']== $n['judul']){ ?>
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="<?= base_url('absensi/absen/'. $n['id_pendaftaran']); ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-primary"> Anda Belum Absen</a>';

            <?php }else{ ?>

            <?php } ?>
        }

        if (days < 0 + hours < -11) {
            clearInterval(x);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-block btn-danger"> Absen expired</a>';
        }
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Please, instead of repeating the same sentence several times could you spend some words in explaining _what_ the problem is?

Comment: You format .... poorly

Comment: I have formatted your code so that it is, at least, mostly visible without scrolling left and right so much, but I am also voting to close your question as it is very unclear.  Please follow the request in earlier comments to explain your problem.